# PayPal Express Landing Page and SolutionType having no effect

Tags: paypal-sandbox, paypal, nvp

I am using the PayPal Express NVP checkout process and my customer has a requirement for the following:

- The user is initially presented with the login screen and not the billing page
- The user should not be able to checkout anonymously by credit card

The documentation makes it quite clear that this is possible:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/

Setting the following options should achieve what I require:

SOLUTIONTYPE=Mark

LANDINGPAGE=Login

This stackoverflow article describes how to achieve the second option as part of the account settings which I have also done.

I've cleared all cache and stored cookies yet it appears these properties are having no effect whatsoever.  I am still taken to the billing page and the ability to checkout anonymously remains.

Am I missing something, or is there anything else I need to do to make this work?

Comment: Is there any website or link to test it ?

Answer (score 0):

There is also a setting in the PayPal profile to turn off the guest checkout option. Go to profile/settings, my selling tools, and then Website preferences. Toward the bottom of the page you will find a setting "PayPal Account Optional" which should be turned off and then save the change at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Thanks - yes I've tried that - it's what I alluded to in the question but for some reason the original link is missing.  This also isn't working.  I'm at a loss.

Answer (score 0):

when 'MARK' is passed it overrides the paypal account optional setting. That said, have you tried just passing LANDINGPAGE=LOGIN ? You don't have to pass SOLUTIONTYPE=MARK.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue and came across this post. What solved it for me was an additional property LandingPageSpecified, which must be set to true.